# Using zigbee devices as repeaters without a hub

Tags: zigbee

I want to use a Spruce smart irrigation controller (it connects to wifi through 2.4ghz) with a Spruce soil moisture sensor (connects to the controller via zigbee).  The sensor needs to be a bit far away from the controller with several walls and other interference in the way.  I'd like to use some zigbee outlets as repeaters to get the signal between my Spruce sensor and my Spruce controller, but I don't want to get a Smart Things hub or other smart hub.  It's just not something I need.  Can I use the zigbee outlets as repeaters without a hub for this type of set up?  Will they simply pass the commands along without a hub to coordinate?  I suppose the Spruce controller is somewhat of a hub in that it does connect to the internet via wifi, but I just don't know if the outlets need anything else to relay info.  Thanks.

Comment: If the sensor connects to the controller using Zigbee, then the controller should be a coordinator, and should in theory be able to handle routers (repeaters) between it and the sensor. The problems you may face are the coordinator not accepting joins from anything else but the sensor. Unless this is documented one way or the other, the only way to find out is to try...